# i want to display an extra column to be displayed among my select query results and that extra column result is also a select statement

Tags: google-bigquery

select A,B,C, (select id from tbl2) as D from Tbl1

the D value might be same for each row.

result will be 
[image]

the D column value is Dynamic (it will change every time), i dont want to pass the value manually

Comment: What is the question? Yes, you can run a query like this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is done as below

```
select a.A, a.B, a.C, b.id as D 
from Tbl1 a
left join tbl2 b
on a.some_field_1 = b.some_field_2
```

Comment: Hey Mikhail, yes we can do this but we do not have any comon field to join  its something like we need to add an extra column to our result, that value depends on one select statement (Dynamic)

Comment: @Anil - you must have some logic of how exactly to pick one value off of tbl2 - any logic! do you have something in mind? as soon as you will have it - we will make it work